# Cloudinary async wait upload for multiple images at once then save to array in node js

Tags: node.js, api, cloudinary

Hi I am look for a solution for API server side upload using Node Js  asyc wait functionality for uploading multiple images then catch into an array. I follow this  [link](https://scotch.io/@codebyomar/how-to-upload-multiple-images-with-cloudinary-and-node-js#comments-section) to implement my code. In console it shows the array that I expect, but it does not give me any responses.

Here is what I tried so far,

```
exports.upload_image = async(req, res) =>{
  //let filePaths = req.files.path;

  let multipleUpload = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let upload_len = req.files.length;
    let upload_res = new Array();

      for(let i = 0; i < upload_len; i++)
      {
          let filePath = req.files[i].path;
          await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(filePath, { use_filename: true, unique_filename: false }, function (error, result) {
              if(upload_res.length === upload_len)
              {
                /* resolve promise after upload is complete */
                resolve(upload_res)
              }
              else if(result)
              {
                /*push public_ids in an array */  
                upload_res.push(result.public_id);
              } else if(error) {
                console.log(error)
                reject(error)
              }

          })

      } 
  })
  .then((result) => result)
  .catch((error) => error)

  let upload = await multipleUpload;
  res.json({'response':upload})
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are not calling the function `await multipleUpload()`;

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce, Still not working. it give me an error saying "multipleUpload is not a function"

Comment: You are `await`ing `cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload`, but I don't that returns a promise.

Comment: `await` only works on functions that return a promise, not functions that just take an ordinary callback.  You will have to "promisify" that function (convert callback to a promise) to use it with `await`.

Comment: in this `if(upload_res.length === upload_len)` line of code I modified as `if(upload_res.length == req.files.length-1)` then it gave me the response, but it is only having details for two images while I send three images on postman. Here is the response `{
    "response": [
        "1529884523808bebbb1d5ff29328157080e4e2e5d15a29c5aa34a",
        "1529884523809d2bf46fbe4c12e06481303d85f49f125e18fbd39"
    ]
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would take a different approach here. You are mixing up promises and async/await in a way that is pretty hard to read and debug.

I would do this instead:
Map your files to an array of promises and then call `Promise.all()`:

```
exports.upload_image = async(req, res) =>{
    // res_promises will be an array of promises
    let res_promises = req.files.map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file.path, { use_filename: true, unique_filename: false }, function (error, result) {
            if(error) reject(error)
            else resolve(result.public_id)
        })
    })
    )
    // Promise.all will fire when all promises are resolved 
    Promise.all(res_promises)
    .then(result =>  res.json({'response':upload}))
    .catch((error) => {/*  handle error */ })
}
```

Here's a snippet with a fake upload function and a list of 'files':

```js
function upload(file, fn) {
  // fake upload file, just return file as id
  setTimeout(() => fn(null, {
    public_id: file
  }), Math.floor(Math.random() * 500))
}

// fake req.files
let files = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

let upload_image = () => {
  let upload_res = files.map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    upload(file, (error, result) => {
      if (error) reject(error)
      else resolve(result.public_id);
    })
  }))

  Promise.all(upload_res)
    .then(result => console.log({
      'response': result
    }))
    .catch(error => error)

}
upload_image()
```

Comment: This answer helped me in uploading multiple images at once. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Using async-await within try-catch**
This is an addition to Mark's answer, but with using await within try-catch instead of using then.

The code also returns the secure_url of the uploaded file instead of the public_id.

Note: If you are using an error handling middleware, there is no need for the try-catch wrapper.

```
exports.upload_image = async(req, res) =>{
try{
    // res_promises will be an array of promises
    let res_promises = await req.files.map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file.path, { use_filename: true, unique_filename: false }, function (error, result) {
            if(error) reject(error)
            else resolve(result.secure_url)
        })
    })
    )
    // Promise.all will fire when all promises are resolved 
    let urlArray = await Promise.all(res_promises)

     res.json({'response': urlArray}))
} catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
  }
    
}
```